# Overriding an Android View E.g. MyHeading : TextView

Tags: android, inheritance, xamarin, xamarin.android

Help! Using Xamarin on VS2017, I'm trying to achieve this:

A MyHeading class that I can use anywhere just like a normal TextView class, except that any of the MyHeading instances will inherit the padding/margin/styles/font etc that I only define for MyHeading.

I'm lost and having no luck and can't find anything useful on Google.

I've created MyHeading.cs which inherits from TextView:

```
public class MyHeading : TextView
{
    public MyHeading(Context context) : base(context)
    {

    }
}
```

Then I've also created myheading.xml in the Resources/layout folder that contains this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.my.app.MyHeading    
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textColor="@color/mygrey"
android:textSize="18dp"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:typeface="sans"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
```

Please help! How can I achieve such a simple requirement i.e. to have a re-usable TextView with the same style whenever I use it.

With my code above, the project builds successfully, but when I run it, it bombs out with this:

```
Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$drawable
```

Comment: I would suggest rather using the Android [style xml attribute](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes.html) it's a more common pattern for sharing common styling. As to the issues you are having I believe you would need to add the missing constructor overloads and inflate your custom layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments suggest (and I as well), creating a `style` is more appropriate and a much more common pattern on Android than creating View subclasses.

### Example

#### Resources/values/styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyHeadingStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">18dp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">sans</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">20dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">10dp</item> 
    </style>
    ~~~ other styles ~~~
</resources>
```

#### AXML Example:

```
<TextView
    android:text="StackOverFlow"
    style="@style/MyHeadingStyle" />
```

#### Output:

[image]

Re: [Android Styles and Themes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes.html)

Comment: Thanks very much for this SushiHangover. I went straight past this, but very cool to see that Android supports styles in a similar way to CSS etc. It's working for me now, cheers.

Comment: Hey Sushi, wondering if you may be able to help with my other question here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47958241/android-global-style-for-all-spinners-in-my-app