# Android: Global style for all Spinners in my app

Tags: android, xamarin, layout, xamarin.android, spinner

I'm using Xamarin Android in Visual Studio 2017.

I have a few existing Spinners which are created in xml layout which all work perfectly and are styled exactly how I want them to look. The code for these is typically:

```
        <Spinner
            android:spinnerMode="dialog"
            android:id="@+id/SpnProject"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:paddingStart="8dp"
            android:paddingEnd="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/myspinner"
            android:prompt="@string/project_prompt" />
```

That works great and my little background image is all rendered correctly..

Now I am trying to create some other spinners dynamically, 100% through code (not layout XML). I'm putting them inside a LinearLayout dynamically with my code.

To create one of these, the code is typically:

```
                    Spinner CustomPicker = new Spinner(TheActivity);
                    List<CustomAttributeOption> AttOptions = db.GetCustomAttributeOptions(ThisAtt.AttributeId);
                    ArrayAdapter<CustomAttributeOption> AttOptionsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<CustomAttributeOption>(Activity, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem, AttOptions);
                    CustomPicker.Adapter = AttOptionsAdapter;
                    customAttributeHolder.AddView(CustomPicker, StackerPosition);
```

This code all completely works and a new dynamic Spinner appears on my form.
But it has default styling and I want to apply the same styles as my other spinners, specifically, I want these dynamic spinners to have a specified height = 40dp. I can't seem to be able to specify layoutHeight=40dp anywhere using code? Does it have to be done using styles/xml?

I played around a lot trying to setup a Theme and specifying a style for all Spinners in my Activity, but the app wouldn't build or run.

Ideally, I'd really like to remove the layout_height and layout_width values out of layout XML and just have it defined somewhere ONCE like in a global style for ALL SPINNERS IN MY ENIRE PROJECT kind of thing.

Can this be done, or are you forced to specify width and height for every single widget on a case by case basis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the layout inflater in order to "auto-magically" apply the styles you can defined.

Lets assume you have a "global" style for your `Spinner`:

```
<style name="MySpinnerStyle" parent="android:Widget.Spinner">
    <item name="android:spinnerMode">dialog</item> 
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">40dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">8dp</item> 
    <item name="android:paddingTop">8dp</item> 
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">8dp</item> 
    <item name="android:paddingStart">8dp</item> 
    <item name="android:paddingEnd">8dp</item> 
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/myspinner</item> 
    <item name="android:prompt">@string/project_prompt</item> 
</style>
```

Create an independent `Layout`  for the dynamic Spinner(s) that you create that uses your global Spinner style

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Spinner xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/masterSpinner"
        style="@style/MySpinnerStyle" />
```

Now instead of instancing a new `Spinner`, inflate the *layout* and all the associated properties will be assigned:

```
var spinner = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Spinner, rootLayout, false) as Spinner;
spinner.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem, new string[] { "Stack", "Over", "Flow" });
customAttributeHolder.AddView(spinner, StackerPosition);
```

Comment: Thanks once again SushiHangover. I just got it working, this works beautifully and is a very good tip. In my specific case, I had to make some very subtle changes to your code. This is my final working statement (as I was calling from inside a Fragment):


var CustomPicker = MyActivity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.dynamicspinner, myLinearLayout, false) as Spinner;

Comment: Hey Sushi, do you know if I can reduce the markup of my static spinners to be minimal like this, so that they get their layout and styles from the masterSpinner layout file just like the dynamic ones do now? Something like:

<Spinner
                android:id="@+id/SpnProject"
                android:prompt="@string/project_prompt"  
                android:style="@styles/masterSpinner" />

Comment: @Aaron Missed that last comment, you are either remove the Spinner elements and replace them with an include `<include
        android:id="@+id/someSpinnerId"
        layout="@layout/Spinner" />` or keep the Spinner elements and apply the style with the `android:style="@styles/masterSpinner"`. Make sense?